# Microsoft Jet OLEDB 4.0 connection string for .txt file Format

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, file-io, oledb, oledbconnection

Here is my connection string for .txt file and some piece of code

```
public class FileTransfers
{ 

    public void fileFromDrive(string filename)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
        string fileConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
               file.DirectoryName + 
               "; Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,)';";

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(fileConnectionString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", file.Name), con))
            {
                con.Open();



                using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Attendance");
                    adp.Fill(tbl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I debug records in `tbl` it shows me the data in only one column, but there are 7 multiple columns in my .txt file and hundreds of rows.

I have tried `FMT=Delimited(,), FMT=TabDelimited,FMT=FiXed` but didn't got multiple columns. I know every entry needs a (,) at is end, but I cant do that manually.

Comment: Got Ans: 
Step 1: Question Right click to solution --> properties --> Targeted Plateform to (x86). Step 2: Make a file named schema.ini in same folder where your data record file is present, Now open up schema.ini and file write [YourFileName] in the next line write Format=TabDelimited

Comment: Yes i solved it in two steps and got table having separate columns feeling Good :)

Comment: I have referenced your solution for the future use as a question with some details. glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are some details you need to consider doing this process as Jan Schreuder mentions in his article [Using OleDb to Import Text Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom),

> The Jet engine makes assumptions about the content of the file. This
>   can result in incorrect imports. For example, it might think a column
>   contains date values. But in fact, your file should treat the columns
>   as a string. In these cases, you should create a Schema.Ini file that
>   describes the type of value for each column. The class creates a
>   Schema.Ini file before it opens the delimited file, but only to
>   specify what the delimiter is. You may want to change this to use
>   pre-defined INI files that describe your input file.

So go ahead and create the `schema.ini` file as prescribed and you issue will be all gone. It's contents should be looking like this,

```
[FileName.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
```

For more details on how tos refer to the following MSDN guide,

[Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx)